# Cin isn't waiting for input

Tags: c++, cin

This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){


string strKingdom = "";
bool conquered_me;//see if was conquered, was going to use this on other program and true = game over.
int gold;
int food;
int citizens;
int soldiers;



cout << endl <<"Name of kingdom: ";
cin >> strKingdom;
cout << endl << "were you conquered (true/false): ";
cin >> conquered_me;
cout << endl << "How many gold do you have?:";
cin>>gold;
cout << endl << "How many food do you have?:";
cin >> food;
cout << endl << "How many citizens do you have?:";
cin >> citizens;
cout << endl << "How many soldiers do you have?:";
cin >> soldiers;


return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I compile it the progam only lets me insert the first 2 variables and then it shows the rest of the questions (after compile):

Name of kingdom: steve

were you conquered (true/false): false

How many gold do you have?:
How many food do you have?:
How many citizens do you have?:
How many soldiers do you have?:

Comment: what is the exact input that you are giving it? I am guessing that it is reading the "2" inputs you are giving as "6" values. (Do you have spaces perchance in your name of the kingdom? Take a look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: just don't use `istream::operator>>`. It's very hard to use correctly. For getting user input, use `std::getline()` and parse the resulting string.

Comment: So storing the std::string is the only one that worked.  The data types that follow, including that bool, led to your runaway behavior.  That's a clue for you.  :-)

Comment: `just don't use istream::operator>>.` This is a very stupid advice. Novice  should first *learn* how to use the standard streams, since it is a very basic interface that is used basically everywhere. Once you learn how it works you are allowed to have an opinion on whether use it or no.

Comment: @sbabbi I didn't suggest he doesn't learn standard streams. The `operator>>` interface is very subtle. Why put yourself into danger when you can use `std::getline()` (which ***also works with standard I/O streams…***) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to employ std::getline and std::string to read the various values. (You can then use functions like atoi to parse them.) Here is your code sample using the std::getline function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){


std::string strKingdom = "";
bool conquered_me;//see if was conquered, was going to use this on other program and true = game over.
int gold;
int food;
int citizens;
int soldiers;

std::string tString = ""; // Used to read and subsequently parse the string.


std::cout << std::endl <<"Name of kingdom: ";
std::getline(std::cin,strKingdom);

std::cout << std::endl << "were you conquered (true/false): ";
std::getline(std::cin,tString);
conquered_me = (tString == "true");

std::cout << std::endl << "How many gold do you have?:";
std::getline(std::cin,tString);
gold = std::atoi(tString.c_str());

std::cout << std::endl << "How many food do you have?:";
std::getline(std::cin,tString);
food = std::atoi(tString.c_str());

std::cout << std::endl << "How many citizens do you have?:";
std::getline(std::cin,tString);
citizens = std::atoi(tString.c_str());

std::cout << std::endl << "How many soldiers do you have?:";
std::getline(std::cin,tString);
soldiers = std::atoi(tString.c_str());


return 0;
}
```

Comment: No it does not. For instance the input can be something like "true " (with a space) for `conqured_me` and it will be interpreted as false. Or if you do not input a number in in `gold` or `food` you get an uncaught exception.

Comment: @sbabbi, Actually it's bit more fun that that. We've got stdlib.h and string included there and a `using namespace std` so we get a fun bit of chaos determining which atoi we're going to get, the old C one or the C++11 one.

Comment: @user4581301 Fixed it. Nice catch.

Answer (score 7):

Entering string "true" to the `bool` variable does not work. You should enter `1` or `0`. Your "true" cannot be "consumed", so it's left in the buffer. Next, you're trying to read `int` value, so "true" also does not match. And so on... until the end of the program.

That's how I would do that:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void askForString(string aPrompt, string &aValue) {
    cout << aPrompt << " ";
    cin >> aValue;
}

void askForBool(string aPrompt, bool &aValue) {
    string tString;
    while (1) {
        cout << aPrompt << " ";
        cin >> tString;
        if (tString == "true") {
            aValue = true;
            break;
        } else if (tString == "false") {
            aValue = false;
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "Repeat, please?" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void askForInt(string aPrompt, int &aValue) {
    string tString;
    char *endptr;
    while (1) {
        cout << aPrompt << " ";
        cin >> tString;
        errno = 0;
        aValue = strtol(tString.c_str(), &endptr, 10);
        if (errno || tString.c_str() == endptr || (endptr != NULL && *endptr != 0)) {
            cout << "Repeat, please?" << endl;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    string strKingdom;
    bool conquered_me;
    int gold;
    int food;
    int citizens;
    int soldiers;

    askForString("Name of kingdom:", strKingdom);

    askForBool("were you conquered (true/false):", conquered_me);

    askForInt("How many gold do you have?:", gold);

    askForInt("How many food do you have?:", food);

    askForInt("How many citizens do you have?:", citizens);

    askForInt("How many soldiers do you have?:", soldiers);

    cout << "Kingdom: " << strKingdom << endl;
    cout << "Conquered: " << (conquered_me ? "true" : "false") << endl;
    cout << "Gold: " << gold << endl;
    cout << "Food: " << food << endl;
    cout << "Citizens: " << citizens << endl;
    cout << "Soldiers: " << soldiers << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct, but suggesting a solution and a bit of example code demonstrating the solution would make this answer useful.

Comment: @user4581301: Improved my answer especially for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Bring them all into strings, and convert as needed.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason (probably compatibility with older code) iostreams default to converting `true` to `1` and `false` to `0` during I/O.

That's only the default though--there's a manipulator named `boolalpha` that will set the stream to use `true` and `false` (or localized equivalents) instead.

So, code like:

```
std::cout << 1 == 0;               // produces `0`
std::cout << boolalpha << 1 == 0;  // produces `false`
```

This also works for input, so you can change your code to something like this:

```
cin >> boolalpha >> conquered_me;
```

...and it should work as expected (and in: it should accept inputs of `false` or `true`, and produce values of `false` and `true` from them, and if it doesn't that's bug in the standard library).

Answer (score 1):

None of your read commands check for error.  ALL of them should be written as something like:

```
while (!(std::cin >> strKingdom)) {
    std::cerr << 'Bad input' << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();  // clear the error
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');  // ignore the rest of the line
    // output the same prompt again?
}
```

To make this easier, you might want to write a helper function:

```
template<typename T> void get_input(const char *prompt, T &result) {
    std::cout << prompt << std::endl;
    while (!(std::cin >> result)) {
        std::cerr << 'Bad input' << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << prompt << std::endl; } }
```

You can then specialize that for bool types to read true/false properly...

Comment: ...or you can use `boolalpha` as streams are already designed to support (see my answer for details).

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
cin >> conquered_me;
```

Should be like this:

```
cin >> boolalpha >> conquered_me;
```

Otherwise the input expects either a "0" or a "1".

By using [`boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) your input can be "true" or "false.